# Prove that if $A$ and $B$ are finite, then $A \cup B$ is finite

Tags: elementary-set-theory, proof-writing, proof-verification, solution-verification

Statement: if $A$ and $B$ are finite, then $A \cup B$ is finite

Proof: If $A$ and $B$ are finite, then there exists $m, n \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $A \approx \mathbb{N}_{m}$ and $B \approx \mathbb{N}_{n}$. Let $f: A \xrightarrow[onto]{1-1} \mathbb{N}_{m}$ and $h: B\xrightarrow[onto]{1-1} \mathbb{N}_{n}$. Then $f \cup h: A\cup B \xrightarrow[onto]{1-1} \mathbb{N}_{m+n}$, which shows that $A \cup B \approx \mathbb{N}_{m+n}$. Thus $A \cup B$ is finite.

Is this proof valid?

Comment: No, unless you have defined before what $f\cup h$ means.

Comment: @Vinicius: That’s not the problem: $f\cup h$ means exactly what it says. The problem is that in general it isn’t a function here, or injective.

Comment: What axioms are you using?

Comment: @BrianM.Scott, that was my point, i guess the what the op meant for $f\cup h$ wasn't exactly what he had in mind.

Comment: what about reasoning on the max elemets wich exixts since $A$ and $B$ are finite.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your $f\cup h$ need not be a function if $A\cap B\ne\varnothing$, and in general it isn’t one-to-one.

HINT: Assuming that $A\cap B=\varnothing$, you can define

$$g:A\cup B\to\Bbb N_{m+n}:x\mapsto\begin{cases}
f(x),&\text{if }x\in A\\
m+h(x),&\text{if }x\in B
\end{cases}$$

and prove that $g$ is a bijection. But the problem doesn’t say that $A$ and $B$ are disjoint; can you see how to modify this idea to handle the possibility that $A$ and $B$ overlap?